# С++ (ImGui) . Как при отображении меню блокировать события мыши в основной игре

Tags: c++, imgui

Я создаю чит-меню на языке C++ с использованием ImGui.
Но при нажатии в чит-меню на какую-нибудь кнопку, основная игра (GTA 5) обрабатывает события мыши (т.е. ЛКМ) и персонаж начинает атаку и мешает ходу выполнения функций вызываемых чит-меню.
Я хочу чтобы GTA 5 при открытом меню не обрабатывала событию мыши (ЛКМ)

Я пробовал WantCaptureMouse, но безуспешно.

Comment: Ну так не обрабатывайте их в игре.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.